# Rails - sending multiple http requests to a another server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, optimization, net-http

1000 users make a request to my Rails server at exactly the same time. For each user, I need to make 50 http requests to other servers, each taking 1 second to respond. How do I go about coding my application so that I can respond to the users as quickly as possible?

*(Note: the app hasn't launched and the numbers are hypothetical.)*

Comment: WTF. why do you need to make 50 http request PER USER?!

Comment: Ah, I was worried this would happen...! The question is to help me design the application.  If there is a way of responding to all of these users very quickly, then I don't need to worry about how many requests I make per user (and 50 would not be unreasonable for some users if there is no reason to cap it). What would you suggest as a cap then and why? And how would you then answer the question?

Comment: see the answer i wrote :)

Comment: I've edited my question slightly.  I appreciate your answer, but I cannot seem to ask the question in such a way that I get the answer I want.  I would expect the answer to talk about threading and possibly processes, whether I should use threading at a User level or Application level, etc. For example, if the optimum number of threads for a single user is 10, is it still the optimum number of threads per user when multiple users connect to the site?  If not, why not, and how do I optimise?  I want to really understand this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement a Job queuing system with ActiveJob and for example Sidekiq.

So your workers can make these 50 http requests.

You'll have to tell the user to be patient while your server is making these requests. This way, the user get's instantly a message which says that there's something going on, you could then notify the user if the jobs have finished.